# python regex parsing data from extremely complicated ingredients string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a string that contains some terribly formatted ingredients list (shortened for this example):

```
Vitamin A 6,000iu/kg, Vitamin D3 80iu/kg, Vitamin E PLUS 240iu/kg
```

I want to break the string down into a list containing the format `[label, amount, units]`:

```
[[Vitamin A, 6000, iu/kg], ...]
```

The problem is there are `,` in the numbers (ie, `6,000`) and as a separator. I can't simply split by comma. The labels can be any number of letters/numbers (ie, `Super Duper Vitamin c4390 4.5iu/kg`), which makes distinguishing between labels and amount even harder. the units can vary from `mg/kg` and `iu/kg`. The list is not restricted to `Vitamin` ingredients. It can contain other words like `Potassium`. There are decimals as well.

The other problem is that there are edge cases:

**Edge cases**: missing space after comma ***AND*** some ingredients may be missing a comma separator.

```
Vitamin A 6,000iu/kg,Vitamin D3 80iu/kg Vitamin E PLUS 240iu/kg, Potassium 3.2mg/kg
```

The best I can do is this regex:

```
^(([a-zA-Z]*\s+)*(\d+[,]?\d+)([a-z\/]*))
```

Which (not quite) matches the first ingredient, and it doesn't handle any of the edge cases. How can I extract the data I want from this messy string?

**EDIT**:

[Here is a real example](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cb%28[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z%20%5Ct]*%29%5Cw%2B%28%5Cd%2B[%2C]%3F%5Cd%2B%29%28[a-z%5C%2F]*%29%2C[%20%5Ct]*&test_string=Vitamin%20A%2015%2C000iu%2Fkg%2CVitamin%20D3%202%2C000iu%2Fkg%2C%20Vitamin%20E%20200iu%2Fkg%2CZinc%20Sulphate%20Monohydrate%20417mg%2Fkg%2C%20Manganous%20Oxide%20131mg%2Fkg%2CFerrous%20Sulphate%20Monohydrate%20297mg%2Fkg%2C%20Calcium%20Iodate%20Anhydrous%207.9mg%2Fkg%2C%20Sodium%20Molybdate%206.4mg%2Fkg%2CCupric%20Sulphate%20Pentahydrate%202.4mg%2Fkg%20Sodium%20Selenite%200.2mg%2Fkg&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: `\b([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z \t]*)\w+(\d+[,]?\d+)([a-z\/]*),[ \t]*` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
([a-zA-Z\s0-9]+)\s+([\d,.]+)([^, ]+)(?=,|$|\s)
```

Try this.You need not split.Use `re.findall`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/32

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z\s0-9]+)\s+([\d,.]+)([^, ]+)(?=,|$|\s)', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = "Vitamin A 6,000iu/kg, Vitamin D3 80iu/kg, Vitamin E PLUS 240iu/k"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Output:`[('Vitamin A', '6,000', 'iu/kg'), (' Vitamin D3', '80', 'iu/kg'), (' Vitamin E PLUS', '240', 'iu/k')]`

Comment: You're really close. I edited my post with a real example. The last few matches don't work. Because there are decimals

Answer (score 1):

For complex regexes I'd suggest that you use extended mode, multiline literals and named groups. This greatly improves readability. Example:

```
rx = r"""(?x)

    \s*

    (?P<label>
        [^,]+?
    )

    \s+

    (?P<amount>
        \d\d? (,\d{3})* (\.\d\d?)?
        |
        \d+
    )

    \s*

    (?P<unit>
        [a-z][a-z]?
        /
        [a-z][a-z]?
    )
"""
```

Usage:

```
s = "Vitamin A 6,000iu/kg,Vitamin D3 80iu/kg,     Vitamin E PLUS 240iu/kg,W E I R D66      66,666 x/cm"

for x in re.finditer(rx, s):
    print x.groupdict()
```

Result:

```
{'amount': '6,000', 'unit': 'iu/kg', 'label': 'Vitamin A'}
{'amount': '80', 'unit': 'iu/kg', 'label': 'Vitamin D3'}
{'amount': '240', 'unit': 'iu/kg', 'label': 'Vitamin E PLUS'}
{'amount': '66,666', 'unit': 'x/cm', 'label': 'W E I R D66'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex. `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` matches floating point numbers.

```
(?:^|,)?\s*(.*?)\s+((?:\d+,)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([a-z\/]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eI6aL6/5)

```
>>> s = "Vitamin A 15,000iu/kg,Vitamin D3 2,000iu/kg, Vitamin E 200iu/kg,Zinc Sulphate Monohydrate 417mg/kg, Manganous Oxide 131mg/kg,Ferrous Sulphate Monohydrate 297mg/kg, Calcium Iodate Anhydrous 7.9mg/kg, Sodium Molybdate 6.4mg/kg,Cupric Sulphate Pentahydrate 2.4mg/kg Sodium Selenite 0.2mg/kg"
>>> re.findall(r'(?:^|,)?\s*(.*?)\s+((?:\d+,)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([a-z\/]*)', s)
[('Vitamin A', '15,000', 'iu/kg'), ('Vitamin D3', '2,000', 'iu/kg'), ('Vitamin E', '200', 'iu/kg'), ('Zinc Sulphate Monohydrate', '417', 'mg/kg'), ('Manganous Oxide', '131', 'mg/kg'), ('Ferrous Sulphate Monohydrate', '297', 'mg/kg'), ('Calcium Iodate Anhydrous', '7.9', 'mg/kg'), ('Sodium Molybdate', '6.4', 'mg/kg'), ('Cupric Sulphate Pentahydrate', '2.4', 'mg/kg'), ('Sodium Selenite', '0.2', 'mg/kg')]
>>>
```

Comment: Hi, you're really close. I forgot to mention that there could be decimals for the amount. I updated my post